# convert an sql query to Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

following sql query is working and gets the visits per day for the current month

```
select  date(date) as DayDate, count(*) As visitsaday from Visits group by DayDate having DayDate between date('now','start of month') and date('now','start of month','+1 month','-1 day')
```

For days I try to figure out how to get this running with the entity Framework.
My best aproach so far ist this:

```
ObjectQuery<Visit> visits = fitent.VisitMenge;
                var uQuery =
                    from visit in visits
                    group visit by visit.Date into g
                    select new
                    {
                        DayOfMonth = g.Key,
                        VisitsPerDay = g.Count()
                    };
```

The Problem here is, that it will be grouped by Date + time instead of just the Date.
An result is like:

```
[0] = { DayOfMonth = {06.07.2009 12:38:59}, VisitsPerDay = 1 }
```

but it should look like

```
[0] = { DayOfMonth = {06.07.2009}, VisitsPerDay = 12 }
```

- How can the Date Format changed which
  is used for grouping ?
- How to filter Just the Days of the
  current Month like in the SQL Query ?

Answer (score 2):

Could you do this:

```
ObjectQuery<Visit> visits = fitent.VisitMenge;
var uQuery = from visit in visits
             group visit by visit.Date.Day into g
             select new
             {
                 DayOfMonth = g.Key,
                 VisitsPerDay = g.Count()
             };
```

Just add a `.Day` to your "visit.Date" - does that work??

Marc

Answer (score 2):

You need to do two things:

- Restrict results by the date with a *where*
- Make **DayOfMonth** just the *date* and not the full *DateTime*

-

```
var uQuery = from visit in visits
             where visit.Date.Month == DateTime.Now.Month 
                 && visit.Date.Year == DateTime.Now.Year
             group visit by visit.Date into g
             select new
             {
                 DayOfMonth = g.Key.Date,
                 VisitsPerDay = g.Count()
             };
```

Answer (score 2):

I now use following:

```
ObjectQuery<Visit> visits = fitent.VisitMenge;
                var uQuery =
                    from visit in visits
                    where visit.Date.Value.Month == DateTime.Now.Month
                 && visit.Date.Value.Year == DateTime.Now.Year
                    group visit by visit.Date.Value.Day into g
                    select new
                    {
                        DayOfMonth = g.Key,
                        VisitsPerDay = g.Count()
                    };
```

The suggested Solutions working fine together!

I had to change just a litle bit

instead of
    visit.Date.Day
I had to:

```
visit.Date.Value.Day
```

I now have an result like:

```
[0] = { DayOfMonth = 6, VisitsPerDay = 3 }
```

Thank you !

Comment: which one are you referring to?